# Cannot delete files from wwwroot with Dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm trying this on Windows Server Core 2016 TP5. I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/iis

RUN powershell remove-item c:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.*
```

The `microsoft/iis` image contains a couple of files (`iisstart.htm` and `iisstart.png`) in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`. I'm trying to remove those files.

Here's the output from docker build:

```
c:\git\temp\test>docker build -t foo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM microsoft/iis
 ---> c26f4ceb81db
Step 2 : RUN powershell remove-item c:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.*
 ---> Running in 4d17a5ab86e5
 ---> d5f85251b3db
Removing intermediate container 4d17a5ab86e5
Successfully built d5f85251b3db
```

If I now start up a container and look in `wwwroot`, the files are still there.

`docker run --rm -it foo cmd`

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14300]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cd inetpub\wwwroot

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5664-BDCB

 Directory of C:\inetpub\wwwroot

05/19/2016  07:05 PM    <DIR>          .
05/19/2016  07:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/05/2016  03:27 PM               703 iisstart.htm
05/05/2016  03:27 PM            99,710 iisstart.png
               2 File(s)        100,413 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  21,209,399,296 bytes free

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>
```

While inside the running container, if I execute `powershell remove-item c:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.*`, the files get deleted fine. Why doesn't the same command work in the dockerfile?

I've also tried `del c:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.*` with similar results.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I can reproduce. Can you open an issue for Docker and cc jhowardmsft: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues

Comment: Done. Thanks! https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22855

Answer (score 0):

You are going to wrong path `C:\>cd inetpub\wwwroot`

You have to go to your container path so:

After run `-d your image`

1. `docker exec -it "containerID" pwoershell`
2. `C:\>cd inetpub\wwwroot`
3. `ls`

And that will be OK as your Dockerfiles works